# Null Value from JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am having some null value issues that is being parsed from JSON. Since I am linking the entity with UILabel's when it see's a null type, it crashes the application. Is there any good approach to show null value on the view than checking for null on every set of linkage?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The class [NSNull](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is intended for situations like this. It is used in collections where the value `null` (0x0) is not allowed (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc.)

Usage of it is similar to the following:

```
id myValue = // get value from collection

// method one (recommended, as you could have more than one instance of NSNull)
if ([myValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class])
{
    // null value
}

// method two, not recommended
if (myValue == [NSNull null])
{
    // null value
}
```

Comment: Thats for the solution but what if there is some entity as null within the dictionary or an array? Would I have to iterate through all of them to make some value than null?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (objectHoldingJsonValue == [NSNull null]) {
   // you have a null value, move in other value
}
```

Comment: Note that you can have more than one instance of `NSNull` in your application, so I would recommend actually using `-isKindOfClass:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid traversing the collections in the JSON objects, you could sub-class UILabel and over-ride the setter for the "text" property, validating the value against it being NULL (for example, using Richard's approach):

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *)textValue
{
    if ([textValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) textValue = nil;
    [super setText:textValue];           
}
```

Of course, taking this approach leaves you open to any other situations in your app where this NULL value could cause you trouble, which is why validating/scrubbing in the context of your data model would probably be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way for a rooting NULLs out of a JSON dictionary. Works with NSDictionary, doesn't have to be mutable:

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) [dictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithString:@""] forKey:key];
} ];
```